# validating card expiry date in playframework

Tags: java, playframework

In my `play1.2.4` app,I need to make sure that a customer's `MembershipCard` is valid at the moment of processing.Validity is determined by the `expiry month and expiry year` together.

If the MembershipCard is

```
class MembershipCard extends Model{

    public String memberShipNumber;

    public String expiryMonth;

    public String expiryYear;

}
```

In controller method which takes the user selected card details(from a dropdown list),I need to make sure that the card is valid.

The String values for ,say the month of `January` is `'1'`.For current year ,it will be `'2012'`.

How can I do the validation on these fields?Do I need to write a custom validator? or can I use the built in '`InFuture`' validation ?(since that one is made for date comparisons)

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom validator, it seems a better option as the *InFuture* validation will require you to transform the Strings to Dates in the request.

*EDIT on comment*

There is a sample in the source code of Play, the [EqualsCheck](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/data/validation/EqualsCheck.java) validator. Create your own version and apply it using [@CheckWith annotation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/validation#custom).

Comment: can you give me a pointer as to how to deal with the two fields(month,year) in the custom validator?Most of the validators in framework code deal with only one field at a time(Minsize etc)